# External hard drive is not recognised in Ubuntu but in MacOS

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive, data-recovery, macosx

I'm trying to recover data from an external hard drive. It's rather large (1 TB) and was originally formatted for Windows using either NTFS or FAT32. In Windows, the hard drive is not recognised anymore. When I first plugged it into my laptop running Ubuntu 19.04, it was recognised in the file explorer but couldn't be accessed (hence the recovery).

Since then, when I plug it in my Ubuntu laptop, it's not mounted anymore. However, when I plug it into my old MacBook, it shows up in the file explorer.

Back to Ubuntu: when I use `lsusb`, it is listed. But it is neiter listed when I enter `lsblk` nor `mount`.

Any idea how I could have it listed in Ubuntu again?

Comment: It may not be possible to recover data, since it looks like there is a hardware problem with that device. You should check what the log shows after it is plugged in: `dmesg |  tail`.

Comment: Being recognized (eg. mac file explorer) maybe because it can read a KB or two of data, but doesn't mean you can access files on the device. You'd have to look at the source code to see what it actually reads before it 'shows'. I would start at basics, check drive health (ie. SMART data) before planning recovery strategy.

Comment: What do you mean by "looking at the source code"?